# impact of allowing Apache to execute some commands on the server

Tags: php, privileges

I have an Ubuntu 12 web server running apache2, I developed a graphic interface using PHP to make users able to create their own email account by themselves ( exec() function), so  I used visudo to let apache only execute some commands ( useradd) with root privileges as follow

> www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/useradd

I wonder if someone can show me security impact on the server of such manipulation

Comment: I would say that is a very bad idea. Your web i/f is allowed to create system accounts with whatever UID/GID it wants. This means that a user could create an account that has root privileges, and would be able to own your box.

Comment: Games can also be played if you're not cautious in what usernames are allowed to be passed in. Someone could do a username like this: `"username; rm -fr /"` for example, and this command would finish off the useradd, and then run their tag along command of `rm -fr *`.

Comment: @slm I have a function to valid inputs so special char are not allowed

Comment: There are often times libraries for sanitizing input, I would encourage you to use one of those if you can.

Comment: @slm give me a shine please.

Comment: There are many examples of what to use here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php. If you want a recommendation: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @slm I'm actually using Var_filter() under PHP it's quit powerful

Comment: Yes there are many choices 8-). The key is to be using a library to do this and not rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can create other users with uid=0, gid=0 and a shell. So they are just the same as root but with different name and have not password assigned.

Normally you'd need a wrapper: A shell script for users with a special group and /bin/false as shell.

Comment: what about security impact of my method ?

Comment: it depends on your requirements, if you don't want to have many users with root rights then it is a security flaw.

Comment: i used visudo so apache can only execute specified cmds, in my case "adduser"